# PHP load json data, output is empty

Tags: php, json

I try to load data from my JSON file into php see my code below

JSON:

```
{
    "drinks":[

    "1" {"coffee": "zwart", "country":"afrika"},
    
    "2" {"tea": "thee", "country":"china"},

    "3" {"water": "water", "country":"netherlands"},
    ]
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$drinks = $json['drinks'][0][coffee];

echo $drinks;
?>
```

If I run this code my output is empty. Who can help me in the right direction?

Comment: Try to add colon after `"1"` like this: `"1" : {....`

Comment: Looks like this json is invalid.

Comment: In addition, `coffee` should be in quotes and your `drinks` are not zero indexed, they are one indexed. In fact they are indexed by strings instead of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 ([JSON specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/)). So the correct json string must be:

```
   {"drinks":[
              {"coffee": "zwart", "country":"afrika"},
              {"tea": "thee", "country":"china"},
              {"water": "water", "country":"netherlands"}
            ]
    }
```

so your code would work:

```
$str = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);    
$drinks = $json['drinks'][0]['coffee'];
echo $drinks;
```

Or at least, you must format your json string like below:

```
{
    "drinks":[    
      {
       "1": {"coffee": "zwart", "country":"afrika"},    
       "2": {"tea": "thee", "country":"china"},    
       "3": {"water": "water", "country":"netherlands"}
      }
   ]
}
```

And you can get your data in this way:

```
$str = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$drinks = $json['drinks'][0]['1']['coffee'];
echo $drinks;
```

Comment: Perhaps just a language barrier thing, but what do you mean in the 2nd half of your answer?  It "must" be the first answer but it "at least must" be formatted like the second?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think the first one is a better option. Thanks for pointing out anyway.